# Update multiples columns using PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

How do i add multiples columns in pdo for update?  this is what I am trying to do but I need to update multiple **$_POSTS['VARS];**

```
$consulta = $conexao_pdo->prepare('UPDATE user SET nome = ? WHERE id = ?');
$consulta->bindParam(1, $variavel_com_nome);
$consulta->bindParam(2, $id);
if ($consulta->execute()) {
  echo 'UPDATED';
}
```

Comment: What is it that is not working in your code? If you need to update multiple columns, you just need to include them in your update statement: `update table1 set col1 = ?, col2 = ?, col3 = ? where id = ?;` then assign parameter values for each one.

Comment: It's working this way thanks

Comment: Did my suggestion fix your problem? If so, I will add it as an answer.

Comment: No need I already gave a upvote on your comment

Comment: Yes, but a question should have an actual answer to close it out properly. I have moved the comment down to an answer. If that was what you were looking for, please accept that as the answer and upvote if you like. That way if anyone has a similar question, it will show as an answered question.

Comment: If you could, make sure you mark it as accepted, not just upvoted. That way the question will be flagged as answered.

Comment: I solved it in another way latter I will post the answer but it's nice the way you did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved it

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET name = :name, 
            surname = :surname
            WHERE username = :username";

            //db column and value
$stmt = $conexao_pdo->prepare($sql);  
//where clause                                 
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);  
//add vars to db      
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $var);    
$stmt->bindParam(':surname', $var);

$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

What is it that is not working in your code? If you need to update multiple columns, you just need to include them in your update statement: update table1 set col1 = ?, col2 = ?, col3 = ? where id = ?; then assign parameter values for each one.